# Combining figma.showUI with Property Menu on Widget

Tags: widget, figma

I am trying to achieve something with a custom widget that I want to utilize within FigJam. I want to be able to trigger an iFrame using the figma.showUI function upon pressing on a button inside the Property Menu.

If you try this widget: https://www.figma.com/community/widget/1037307041437991195

You will see that clicking on the Edit button will trigger this Settings Pop-up on the right hand-side.

[image]

Unfortunately, this is not my widget - but I want to build the same functionality. I cannot figure it out for the life of me and cannot find anything from within the documentation.

I do know how I can make the UI be triggered from clicking somewhere on the widget itself (and you can see the same also in one of the example widget provided by Figma: https://github.com/figma/widget-samples/blob/main/WidgetToast/widget-src/code.tsx or in this help article: https://www.figma.com/widget-docs/handling-user-events/#iframes

Find my working example code here that I adjusted slightly

```js
const { widget } = figma
const { Text, useSyncedState, useEffect } = widget
function IFrameExample() {
  const [name, setName] = useSyncedState('name', '[Enter your name]')
  useEffect(() => {
    figma.ui.onmessage = (message) => {
      if (message.type === 'name') {
        setName(message.name)
        figma.closePlugin()
      }
    }
  })
  function showSettings(){
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
      figma.showUI(`
        <input id="name" type="text" placeholder="Name">
        <button id="submit">Submit</button>
        <script>
          document.getElementById('submit').onclick = () => {
            const textbox = document.getElementById('name')
            const name = textbox.value
            const message = { pluginMessage: {type: 'name', name} }
            parent.postMessage(message, '*')
          }
        </script>
    `)
    })
  }
  return (
    <Text onClick={showSettings}>
      Hello {name}
    </Text>
  )
}
widget.register(IFrameExample)
```

Would appreciate any help or pointers in the right direction!

I put the figma.showUI part in a separate function, so I can make it callable by the Property Menu in the next step. Find my code below where I have that integrated:

```js
const { widget } = figma
const { usePropertyMenu, Text, useSyncedState, useEffect } = widget
function IFrameExample() {
  const [name, setName] = useSyncedState('name', '[Enter your name]')
  const [setting, setSetting] = useSyncedState<string>('setting', 'do_nothing');

  useEffect(() => {
    figma.ui.onmessage = (message) => {
      if (message.type === 'name') {
        setName(message.name)
        figma.closePlugin()
      }
    }
  })
  function showSettings(){
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
      figma.showUI(`
        <input id="name" type="text" placeholder="Name">
        <button id="submit">Submit</button>
        <script>
          document.getElementById('submit').onclick = () => {
            const textbox = document.getElementById('name')
            const name = textbox.value
            const message = { pluginMessage: {type: 'name', name} }
            parent.postMessage(message, '*')
          }
        </script>
    `)
    })
  }
  //adding the property menu
  const settingsOptions = [
    { option: 'do_nothing', label: 'Do Nothing' },
    { option: 'open_settings', label: 'Open Settings' },
  ];

  usePropertyMenu(
    [
      {
        itemType: 'dropdown',
        propertyName: 'settings',
        tooltip: 'Settings selector',
        selectedOption: setting,
        options: settingsOptions,
      }
    ],
    ({ propertyName, propertyValue }) => {
     if (propertyName === 'settings') {
        setSetting(propertyValue);
        showSettings();
      }
    }
  );
  return (
    <Text onClick={showSettings}>
      Hello {name}
    </Text>
  )
}
widget.register(IFrameExample)
```

With this code, if you select the option "Open Settings" you will see that the popup will show up for a split second and disappear again. In the console I will get the error message

> `figma_app.min.js.br:5` Your widget was terminated before `figma.showUI` could finish running. Return a promise in your event handler to keep your widget running while your iframe is open. For more information, see: [https://www.figma.com/widget-docs/handling-user-events/`](https://www.figma.com/widget-docs/handling-user-events/%60)

But I could not figure out how to make it work, even with the documentation.